# Is there a way to get from PayPal a user's recurrent payments that are currently active?

Tags: oauth-2.0, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

Currently I'm looking for a way to interrogate PayPal API so I can get access to users specific data like the recurrent payments.
Though I can't find a way to properly setup the request, also I didn't find a lot of stuff about this inside the PayPal API docs.

This is my code, which is running in AWS through lambda.

```
import json
import urllib.parse

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    CLIENT_ID = '\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*'
    REDIRECT_URL = '....'
    SCOPES = 'openid profile email https://uri.paypal.com/services/subscriptions'

    encoded_scopes = urllib.parse.quote(SCOPES, safe='')
    
    auth_url = f'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/signin/authorize?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URL}&response_type=code&scope={encoded_scopes}'
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps({'auth_url': auth_url}),
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a Log in with PayPal integration. It will return the PayPal ID of the user who logged in, it will not return anything else relevant to subscriptions.

You need to store active subscriptions and users in your own database. Subscribe to the webhook event `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED` and use this to update your profiles' good-through date.

When creating a subscription you can add a `custom_id` with your own reference value which will be returned in responses. This can aid in reconciling later events with the user/profile in your system.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe the question was not clear enough.
I'm trying to implement an application that shows the user his active recurring payments in his account.
I'm not creating any subscriptions!

Comment: "I'm looking for a way to interrogate PayPal API so I can get access to users specific data like the recurrent payments" -- any recurring payments happening automatically at PayPal's end would be PayPal Subscriptions, which cannot be queried. If there are recurring payments of another type, the information will not be at PayPal

Comment: But I see in the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/) that this is kind of possible, for example interrogating /v1/billing/plans
Am I missing something?

Comment: Plans are a billing cycle schema, they are for setting up subscriptions at checkout time, or for changing the billing cycle in the future; there is no other purpose to plan objects

Comment: So basically there's no way to setup what I want to do, because in PayPal there are not ways to ask for all the user current recurrent payments, right?